# Question about proving ceiling function equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I read a proof about ceiling function equivalence relation as linked [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ceiling_defines_Equivalence_Relation).
The theorem to prove is:

Let $\mathcal R$ be the relation defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that: $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}: \left({x, y}\right) \in \mathcal R \iff \left \lceil {x}\right \rceil = \left \lceil {y}\right \rceil$
where $\left \lceil {x}\right \rceil$ is the ceiling of $x$.
Then $\mathcal R$ is an equivalence.

Proving reflexitivity and symmetry is trivial, but I have questions about proving transitivity.
According to definition, we should just proof that if $\left \lceil {x}\right \rceil = \left \lceil {y}\right \rceil$ and $\left \lceil {y}\right \rceil = \left \lceil {z}\right \rceil$, then $\left \lceil {x}\right \rceil = \left \lceil {z}\right \rceil$. In the proof, the author took extra steps to prove this. But isn't $\left \lceil {x}\right \rceil = \left \lceil {y}\right \rceil = \left \lceil {z}\right \rceil$ trivial? Are there any reason why the author went those extra steps?

Comment: I agree that it ought to be trivial.  The ceiling function should at this point be understood to be a *function* at which point transitivity follows from the transitivity of $=$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is trivial. Actually, it is so trivial that it has nothing to do with the ceiling function. If $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is any function and if you define a binary relation $\sim$ on $X$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.